# jQuery Class Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The context of which I'm working with is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/888egs94/1/

To achieve the following I've been using (what seems like) a hundred versions of

```
$('.two').click(function() {
      if($('.two')){
        $('.two').addClass("one");
        $('.two').removeClass("two") }
}
```

But I *know* there must be a simpler way. I am completely new to jQuery as of today. Trying to generate something like a conveyor belt for a client.

1. User clicks on .two:

   - .two adds .one class, removes .two class
   - .three adds .two class, removes .three class
   - .one adds .three class, removes .one class
2. User clicks on .three:

   - .three adds .two class, removes .three class
   - .two adds .one class, removes .two class
   - .one adds .three class, removes .one class
   - .two adds .one class, removes .two class
3. User clicks on .one:

   - modal opens.

It's essentially a carousel but inheriting classes if that makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have the animation down, it's just getting the classes right and consistent (so that they're not overlapping or moving when they're not supposed to).

Comment: `if($('.two')){` makes no sense, it will always be true.

Comment: Are you the same poster who asked a question about cycling in jQuery a little while ago? The question seems to be deleted now.

Comment: Your fiddle never runs the function that executes this code. It also doesn't load jQuery.

Comment: Post your code here, not at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 2):

A lot is going on here:

1. As was already pointed out, your `if` statement is not checking for a true or false, it's simply selecting some elements.
2. The way your css is set up, even if the elements moved to their new spots, you wouldn't notice. The middle block `.two` is always yellow and always in the middle. So if I give another block the class of `.two` it would just instantly update itself to be in that spot. You could fix this by using different classes to assign color.
3. Finally, you don't have an `else` statement to check if the class is `.one` which would indicate showing a modal instead of rotating blocks.

All that being said, I believe this is what you're looking for. Hopefully you can learn from this example.
http://jsfiddle.net/xph5dgto/1/

Comment: Post your code here as a Stack Snippet instead of at jsfiddle.